# Custom screen dim with Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

In Android when you pop up a dialog the screen behind it dims.  Is there any way to control what that looks like?  For example making it dim more or less or using some kind of a pattern?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can control it.

After creating dialog:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  
lp.dimAmount = 0.0f; // Dim level. 0.0 - no dim, 1.0 - completely opaque
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

**Upd**: you can even add blur behind the dialog:

```
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

**Upd2**: [Blurring is deprecated since API14](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND):

> This constant was deprecated in API level 14.
>   Blurring is no longer supported.

Comment: Wonderful! I'll try that tomorrow!

Comment: blurring is deprecated

Comment: @Mars True. Thanks, added it to answer

Comment: It does nothing on my activity, I don't get why

Answer (score 36):

Or you can do:

```
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.5f);
```

Comment: this call requires at least API level 14

Comment: what about the color of the dim?

Answer (score 19):

This solution did not work for me. There is another option, you can cancel the flag that control dimming. This code worked for me:

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Comment: You should set dialog contentView before setting dimAmount, otherwise there is no effect

Answer (score 18):

Answering it quite late but I am sure things get deprecated with time so my answer would definitely help someone.
First of all create a dialog:

```
dialog = new Dialog(ActivityName.this);
dialog .setCancelable(false);
dialog .setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
```

Then get the window of that dialog and add a flag called FLAG_DIM_BEHIND and finally set the dim amount on the screen.

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
if(window != null){
   window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND); // This flag is required to set otherwise the setDimAmount method will not show any effect
   window.setDimAmount(0.5f); //0 for no dim to 1 for full dim
}
```

Then show your dialog,

```
dialog.show();
```

And before you dismiss your dialog, clear the flags:

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

And then dismiss:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following parameters worked for me on Android 5.1

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.dimAmount = 0.65f;
```

params can be assigned to the dialog.

```
dialog.getWindow().addContentView(view, params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `android:backgroundDimEnabled` and `android:backgroundDimAmount` in the style to enable and modify the dimming amount.

My dialog style looks like this:

```
<style name="LoadingDialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.88</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

and here is my dialog class:

```
public class ProgressView extends Dialog {

public ProgressView(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.LoadingDialog); 
    setTitle(null);
    setCancelable(false);
    setOnCancelListener(null);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.lottie_loading, null);
    setContentView(view); 
}
```

}

and I use it like this in a fragment of an activity:

```
    progressDialog = ProgressView(requireContext())
    progressDialog.show()
```