# How can I change default black dim background "color" (not the amount of dim) of Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

[image]

(This is a random image of showing a `Dialog` found on the Internet.)

I've been implementing a custom `Dialog`. I could handle almost everything on the dialog except for that default black dim background under the dialog itself, but over the entire screen behind it. Basically I want to change its **color** and alpha value.

I've been wandering through StackOverflow but only answers I found were about changing background of `Dialog` itself. In any case if you need it, here's my simple codes.

#### CustomDialog.java

```
public class HTDialog extends Dialog{

    public HTDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    }
}
```

#### custom_dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="280dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_popup"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.yourdrawable);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom screen dim with Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257332/custom-screen-dim-with-dialog)

Comment: @Harry That's not solving my problem because I already have `background` in my `custom_dialog.xml`, which has exactly the same effect.

Comment: @yushi That post deals with the same aspect but is there any way to change the color, not the amount of dim?

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol I don't think so.

Comment: set getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.yourdrawable); will solve the issue.try this please

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a workaround but it's not really a pure solution because background touch is disabled and should be configured manually.

First, set custom dialog theme like this.

#### styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Setting `windowIsFloating` to false forces `Dialog` view to be expanded to full screen. Setting `windowBackground` to `transparent` removes default black dim background under `Dialog`. `windowNoTitle` option gets rid of the upper title bar.

#### CustomDialog.java

Apply the theme and construct your `custom_dialog` view as follows.

```
public HTCustomDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
}
```

#### custom_dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_solid_80">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_root"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_popup"
        android:padding="16dp">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now that `CustomDialog` view is a full-screen view, set `background` of your root layout to whatever color you'd like.

#### Sample result

I mosaiced the result a bit.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

use custom style.

```
<style name="transparent_dialog_borderless" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF333333</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

android:backgroundDimEnabled:control the black dim background

Comment: I tried `background`, which changes the "inside" background of `Dialog`. I tried `windowBackground`, which changes the "outside" background of `Dialog`, which changes the color only within the size of `Dialog`. Could you let me know the item name which deals with the color of `backgroundDim`?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(view)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.done_label, { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() })
                .create()
        dialog.window.setDimAmount(0f)
        dialog.show()
```

`dialog.window.setDimAmount(0f)` is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the style for your dialog windows,

Example:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following custom DatePickerDoalog class not only makes dim color customizable  but also it makes dim appearing animated

```
/**
 * @author Taras Yurkiv @Devlight
 */
public class DatePickerDialogCustomDim extends DatePickerDialog {

    private final long animDuration = 100;
    private float dimAmount = 0.7f;

    private Drawable dimDrawable;
    private ViewGroup root;

    private OnDismissListener outsideDismissListener;

    private final OnDismissListener dismissListener = new OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(dimDrawable,
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("alpha", (int) (255 * dimAmount), 0));
            animator.setTarget(dimDrawable);
            animator.setDuration(animDuration);
            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    ViewGroupOverlay overlay = root.getOverlay();
                    overlay.remove(dimDrawable);
                }
            });
            animator.start();
            if (outsideDismissListener != null)
                outsideDismissListener.onDismiss(dialog);
        }
    };


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public DatePickerDialogCustomDim(@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, 0);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public DatePickerDialogCustomDim(@NonNull Context context, @StyleRes int themeResId) {
        this(context, themeResId, null, -1, -1, -1);
        init(context);
    }

    public DatePickerDialogCustomDim(@NonNull Context context,
                                     @Nullable OnDateSetListener listener,
                                     int year,
                                     int month,
                                     int dayOfMonth) {
        this(context, 0, listener, year, month, dayOfMonth);
    }

    public DatePickerDialogCustomDim(@NonNull Context context,
                                     @StyleRes int themeResId,
                                     @Nullable OnDateSetListener listener,
                                     int year,
                                     int monthOfYear,
                                     int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, themeResId, listener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        root = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        super.setOnDismissListener(dismissListener);
    }

    public void setDimAmount(@FloatRange(from = 0, to = 1f) float dim) {
        dimAmount = dim;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        dimDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE); // a dim color
        dimDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, root.getWidth(), root.getHeight());

        ViewGroupOverlay overlay = root.getOverlay();
        overlay.add(dimDrawable);

        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(dimDrawable,
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("alpha", 0, (int) (255 * dimAmount)));
        animator.setTarget(dimDrawable);
        animator.setDuration(animDuration);
        animator.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnDismissListener(@Nullable OnDismissListener listener) {
        outsideDismissListener = listener;
    }
}
```

it works in conjunction of a style

```
<style name="DatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: why is this not upvoted as the best answer yet??

Answer (score 0):

try the code,

```
View checkBoxView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.alertbox, null);



    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

             builder.setView(checkBoxView);
             builder.setCancelable(false);
                Dialog d = builder.create();

                d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
                d.setView(checkBoxView, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                d.show();
```

nb: the line  d.setView(checkBoxView, 0, 0, 0, 0); will make it...

Comment: What is `d` in the answer?

Answer (score -1):

set a float value for backgroundDimAmount between 0-1 (it is a float value)

```
    <style name="DarkTransparentBgDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
       <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
       <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.87</item>
    </style>
```

in DialogFragment (in Kotlin)

```
override fun getTheme() = R.style.DarkTransparentBgDialog
```

Comment: your answer explains how to change the dim opacity value, not the dim color which is what the question is asking for.