# Alternative to the deprecated FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND flag for dimming background of Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to dim/blur the backgruond BEHIND a Dialog box. In the past, I've used this code:

```
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

But as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257332/custom-screen-dim-with-dialog) question states, the WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND flag is now deprecated as of API 14. Is there a way I can dim the background of a Dialog box NOT using this flag? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
```

Another alternative:

```
getWindow().setBackground(new ColorDrawable(0x7000000))
```

Comment: This is not blur just black!

Comment: blur and dim are not the same thing

Comment: It does not make the background blur but just dim (which is definetely not the same).

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Code ,  put it before setContentView :

```
 window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
```